# NGINX conf 2 domains + sub domains in separate root folders and www to non-www

Tags: server, configuration, nginx

I've tried to create 2 separate NGINX conf files for two domains. Each domain has a test. sub domain and www shall be permanently redirected to now-www for canonical reasons. I get 2 errors in below code.

sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] server name "$uri/" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:27
nginx: [warn] server name "/index.php$is_args$args" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:27
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:31
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Here's my conf file for example.com, the second file for example2 is almost identical.

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 root /var/www/example.com/html;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name example.com 123.456.7.8;
 #location / {
 #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
 #(For WordPress permalinks)
 }
 # Redirect all traffic to www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons server
 server {
 listen 80; server_name www.example.com;
 location / { return 301 https://www.example.com/$request_uri; }
 location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { default_type "text/plain";
 root /usr/share/nginx/html; allow all; }
 }
 # Direct all traffic to the  subdomain to a separate folder
 server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 root /var/www/test/example.com/html;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name test.example.com

 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
 #(For WordPress permalinks)
 }
 # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
 location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }
 location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
 location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
 location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
 expires max;
 #To enable leverage browser caching log_not_found off;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Since this question is not about Ubuntu, you may get a better answer on ServerFault.

Comment: The error message is caused by a missing `;` at the end of a `server_name` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thx I fixed that now, but now I got nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:19